# Deleting Chrome's History/Cookies/Saved Passwords/etc

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, history

I am trying to delete Chrome's History using Python
I got to know that Chrome saves it's History,Cookies,etc in a Default Folder that is

```
 C:\Users\vaibhav2\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

I tried to remove this folder manually but still Google Chrome has its History all well at it place ,no effect

I wish to delete it
(History/Cookies/Saved Passwords/etc) using Python please tell me the script to do so

Please Help how do I remove History

Comment: Have you ever noticed how your history follows you from PC to PC?

Comment: yeah it is stored in sqlite database?

Comment: So how do i delete it using python ?

Comment: OR access / see the history in sqllite or anything ,any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cookies should be the location. I'm pretty sure you don't need to delete the whole "Default" folder, just the "cookies" file.

Comment: I tried deleting the Entire DEfault file nothing happened neither history nor cookies nothing at all

Comment: Have you run chrome since then?

also have you been able to delete other files on your pc using the method you are trying now?

Comment: No none at all ,

Comment: So you haven't been able to delete any other files either? I'm no good with python but could you post your code here so we can all look at it?